# Is there a way to convert a runtime visual tree back into XAML code / text?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Does anyone know if its possible to convert visual tree elements from runtime back into XAML code?

The scenario would be someone wrote code that makes a UWP UI in code behind... Lets say something simple like Grids with Buttons. Then the development team wants to convert that code into XAML for some nonspecific reason.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I see XamlReader exists; converts Xaml strings to objects i.e. only load functionality.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader

Looking for the converse of this.

Comment: Take a look into the class XamlXmlReader. It could help you for your use case

Comment: @KevinAvignon unfortunately that does not exist for UWP. UWP uses Windows.UI. That class appears to belong to older .Net/System.xaml

Comment: At the moment, there's no such API for you to do it.